# I am having trouble using the Dropdown Event in a 3D chart on R-Ploty

Tags: r, r-plotly

First I do not speak English well. Please understand that point..

I created a data frame like the code I attached in R. What I want to do is draw each x, y, z 3D line graph with the value of the ID column of the data frame. In addition, I want to add a visible event for each ID line via updatemenus.
The other examples are mostly 2D and we are adding a column to the line that we need to add, not just a single column. No matter how I look, I can not do what I want, so write this.

```
df <-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
            x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
            y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
            z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))



p <-plot_ly(df, x= ~x , y= ~y, z=~z,
      type = "scatter3d",
      mode = "Line") %>% 

#add_trace() ?? ,  group_by() ?? , ids ??

  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE,FALSE)),
               label = "id1 visible"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE,TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "id2 visible"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)),
               label = "id3 visible")))
    )
  )
p
```

I wrote the code using the examples in this link.
https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/

plotly There is a reference called 'ids' in the reference, are you using this to assign an id to an object and change the property by separating it? Or through add_trace ()? Or through group_by? It's too confusing. Please help me. I just got a new job, so I do not know too much.

Comment: It looks like in these examples they share the same x values and the y is different

Comment: The examples share x values, but what if I do not have shared data values ​​like my code?